# Exoplayer - displaying preview when calling seekTo multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer2.x

I'm using ExoPlayer for video playback and I have a seekbar to allow user to move back or forward during playback.

What I want to achieve is for user to be able to seek while also be able to preview the frame at the current time relative to the seeker position.

Problem is, the player is displaying black frame until the user lets go of the seekbar. I'm think it's because seekTo is being called multiple times and the player just doesn't have enough time to load the frame?

Any idea how to work around this?

This is how I call the seekTo inside the seekbar listener

```
time_range.setOnRangeSeekbarChangeListener { minValue, maxValue ->
       val mediaUri = Uri.parse(media?.dataUrl)
       player?.prepare(buildClipMediaSource(mediaUri, startTime.toInt(), endTime.toInt()))
       player?.seekTo((startTime * 1000f).toLong())
       player?.playWhenReady = true
}
```

Comment: I think you should `seek` only after user touch up seekbar or finish seeking the widget.

Comment: @CoXier but how can I preview the current frame relative to the seekbar position?